# how to make div 2 is left of div 1 in html?

Tags: html, css

Now am in basic stage to create HTML designing,am create three `div1 div2 div3`.`Div1` is whole page.`Div2` and `Div3` is inside of `Div1` and `Div2` is left of `Div1`. Am added the properties of all the `Div` everything is fine but the `Div2` is move from margin top but i didn't set any margin properties for `Div2`. Help me to solve this issue.

**HTML Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<title>Task 2</title>
</head>
<div class="main-div">

<div class="admin-portal">
</div>

<div class="header-control">
<h3>Just for testing</h3>
</div>

</div>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
 @charset "utf-8";
 /* CSS Document */
.main-div{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background:#FFFFFF;
}
.admin-portal{
  width:12%;
  height:100%;
  line-height:30px;
  padding: 5px;
  float:left;
  background:#008fd3;
}
.header-control{
  width:100%;
  height:10%;
  top:0px;
  background:#008fd3;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the margin in `Div3` is `H3` has margin and you need to remove it:

```
<h3>Just for testing</h3>
```

So your CSS would be:

```css
.header-control h3 {margin: 0;}
```

Or simply, add a reset style:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zx9d6t6L/

Comment: I'd say this is because [margins are collapsed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2s8bb09x/)

add this in cssit will remove all default margin and padding

```
* {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px
}
```